# Как записать данные в hdf4 формат?

Tags: python, анализ-данных

Есть готовый файл с наборами данных

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вытаскиваю данные например с набора m_m22_02_10.6H, умножаю их на 0.5 и хочу записать обратно.
Но не могу найти пример, или документацию.

Или другая постановка задачи:

Есть матрица, необходимо её записать в hdf4 файл.

```py
A = [[1, 4, 5], 
    [5, 8, 9]]

print(A)

# 1 4 5
# 5 8 9
```

Comment: В Python гораздо удобнее работать с HDF5 - этот формат поддерживают многие удобные модули для обработки данных. Может вам конвертировать HDF4 -> HDF5?

Comment: @MaxU к сожалению при конвертации с hdf4 в hdf5 - всё  нормально, а при конвертации назад этого же файла, теряются буквы в мета данных

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
#%pip install pyhdf

# Импортируем API
from pyhdf.SD import SD, SDC
import numpy as np

# Ссылка на файл: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1PMlNviOCcywd8-V0OCFbpRd6bP_N24qO
d = SD('AIRS.2002.08.01.L3.RetStd_H031.v4.0.21.0.G06104133732.hdf', SDC.WRITE)

# Получаем список датасетов, в данном случае я использую датасет Longtitude
datasets = d.datasets()
datasets_names = list(datasets.keys())
print(datasets_names)

ds = d.select('Longitude')
# И выводим данные
print(ds.get())

# Домнажаем данные на 4 для примера
ds.set(ds.get()*4)

# Закрываем файл
# print(ds.get())
d.end()
del d
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно воспользоваться модулем `python-hdf4`:

#### Install

```
pip3 install python-hdf4
```

#### Docs

[**link**](http://fhs.github.io/pyhdf/modules/HDF.html#functions-and-classes-summary)